# Does PHP header() cache the redirect and, if so, how to prevent it from doing that?

Tags: php, redirect, caching

I need to show my users a slightly different version of the front-page before opening date. The idea was to redirect them to `home.html` in the `index.php` (the main-site) by using `header("location:home.html")`, and after the opening, remove that redirect so they load the real `index.php`.

The problem is, if I do that, will the browser cache the redirect and take them to cached version of `home.html` even **after** I have removed the redirect from the `index.php`? If so, how do I prevent that?

The end goal is, show the user *uncached brand new version of the site* after opening date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple kinds of [redirections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections). You want a temporary.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect");
header("Location: https://example.com/home.php");
```

PHP is not caching redirects, but the browser may. So when used temporary it won't.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
header("location:home.html")
```

basically, there will be a redirect to the **home.html** page. `header` itself does not cache anything, it's just a function.

Your browser may cache CSS and JS files, but it will never cache **home.html** itself. **home.html** is being sent from your server to the browser as it is. Yet, of course, you may have server-side caching in your equation, that is, it's possible that even though you have changed **home.html**, it may have been changed in dev mode, whereas, an older **home.html** may be in use on your server, in which case the cache could be emptied, or somehow, depending on your server-cache brand you may force-load **home.html**.

All in all, you should not be worried about caches being used by `header()`, if you have a caching problem on your server-side, empty the cache, or force-load the page. If you are afraid of caching problems in your browser, then you can add some parameter to the URL,  like:

**https://your/path/to/this/file.css?version=3**

and always change this version whenever you have a new release to force browsers to load the new file rather than reuse its older version.